# emberjs, wrong controller in each

Tags: ember.js

If I have a template like so:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="listbeer">
    {{#each controller}}
    <li>{{aname}}</li>
    {{/each}}
    </script>
```

then nothing will get displayed. On the other hand if I do:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="listbeer">
    {{#each DHApp.beerlistController}}
    <li>{{aname}}</li>
    {{/each}}
    </script>
```

it works and I get the list from the controller's content displayed. Why is this? What controller am I seeing in the former case. Note that I have bound them in the view or so I thought with:

```
DHApp.ListbeerView = Ember.View.extend({
        templateName: 'listbeer',
});
DHApp.listbeerView = DHApp.ListbeerView.create({
    controller: DHApp.listbeerController,
    contentBinding: 'controller.content'
});
```

so I'd expect to see the same. Note that the controller is an array one and as i say above its fine if I specify the controller in the each loop

UPDATE:
If I do

```
{{controller}} {{DHApp.listbeerController}}
```

then I get

```
<DHApp.ListbeerController:ember192> <DHApp.ListbeerController:ember149>
```

It looks like I am receiving the default controller not the one I instantiated.

So is there a way to set the controller for the view to my instantiated one. OR a way to get the auto instantiated controller outside the route. 
I want access to the controller so I can update the controller model inside ajax responses, timers and things like that

Comment: Based on the content of your post -- the Beer Controller -- I think we may be working on pretty similar applications (Ember.js-powered beer web-app).  If you're interested in working together on it, I'm game.

Answer (score 0):

Do things improve if you do the following? Because you need to use get and set, instead of accessing the controller directly.

```
DHApp.ListbeerView = Ember.View.extend({
        templateName: 'listbeer',
});
DHApp.listbeerView = DHApp.ListbeerView.create({
    controllerBinding: 'DHApp.listbeerController',
    contentBinding: 'controller.content'
});
```

Also, from the look of your code, you appear to be using an old version of Ember (or implementing the new Ember incorrectly), as controllers can no longer be accessed from the `DHApp` variable if they're instantiated automatically by EmberJS, but [instead dealt with in the router with `this.controllerFor`](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/setting-up-a-controller/).

Comment: P.S: If this doesn't work, could you please knock up a quick JSFiddle with your example?

Comment: Thanks but that code looks the same as I used, did you intend to paste in something else? I am actually instantiating the controller manually as I am wanting to access the controller once an ajax request completes. I'll have a go at changing the controller in the router

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a context issue. By default, controller will be the context of the template it was rendered into. If you do something like:

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="listbeer">
  {{controller}}
  {{#each controller}}
```

Controller will most likely be the ApplicationController (hard to tell without more of the implementation shown).

Typically you would not create controllers directly, but instead allow the router to create the controller, which in turn will help you control the context as desired. There are some good examples in the guide:

http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/rendering-a-template/

Comment: If I do {{controller}}
 {{DHApp.listbeerController}} then I get <DHApp.ListbeerController:ember192> <DHApp.ListbeerController:ember149> so it looks like I am receiving the default controller not the one I instantiated. So is there a way to set the controller for the view to my instantiated one. OR a way to get the auto instantiated controller outside the route. I want to be able to update the controller model inside ajax responses, timers and things like that

Comment: This might be a case where the design approach needs to be modified. There are no easy ways to get access to a controller directly without accessing it from a route/view/controller. Controllers can use the "needs" property to reference other controllers, routers (and possibly views) can use the controllerFor method, there are a few others ways as well. In most cases if I find myself needing direct access to a controller from a global perspective I that is a huge indication that I am probably coming at the problem the wrong way.

Comment: That was kind of my feeling that I shouldn't be globally accessing the controller although some of the Ember.js examples do this in a way when they do something like #each dhApp.beerController. Do you have any advice for a best way to update the model then on ajax requests, timers etc (I am not using Ember Data for now)

Comment: I don't have an example readily available, as I only use ember data, but I would think you'd have a controller that manages a content array and then handles the ajax stuff. So your controller could set up a timer on init to do something like this.reloadData() and then the controller would hit the server and update its content array as needed.